# Streamlit python variable declaration

Tags: python, streamlit

I wrote some dummy code to replicate my problem. I need to do some simple computations in Streamlit, but I can't seem to find out how they handle variables and how to store info
Here is my example:

```
import streamlit as st

sidebarOption = st.sidebar.radio('Options',("A","B","C"))

if sidebarOption == 'A':

    param1 = st.number_input('Value 1', min_value=1.0, max_value=100.0, value =20.0, step=0.1 )
    param2 = st.number_input('Value 2', min_value=1.0, max_value=50.0, value =24.0, step=0.1 )
    
elif sidebarOption == 'B':
    param3 = st.number_input('Value 3', min_value=1.0, max_value=100.0, value =20.0, step=0.1 )
    param4 = st.number_input('Value 4', min_value=1.0, max_value=50.0, value =24.0, step=0.1 )
    

elif sidebarOption == 'C':
    add = param1+param3
    st.write('Add:', add)
```

I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'param1' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: param1 is out of scope or undefined when you select option C.

Comment: I can see that, but how can I make the params available to option C?

Comment: What should `param1` and `param3` be in case C? You only define them in other cases.

Comment: If `sidebarOption` equals `'C'`, it can't have equaled `'A'` or `'B'` as well, so neither `param1` nor `param3` have been defined to allow you to add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with Streamlit, the variables are just not defined. Let me rewrite your code without the Streamlit part and with added comments to see if that clarifies things:

```py
option = 'C'

if option == 'A':
    foo = 1 # this line is not executed, since option is not A
elif option == 'B':
    bar = 2 # this line is not executed, since option is not B
elif option == 'C':
    # the code below is executed, but foo and bar are undefined, so there is an error
    baz = foo + bar
    print(baz)
```

Does the error make more sense? If you want to add `foo` and `bar`, they must be defined first, which is not the case here.

If you are sure that the code will be called with options A and B before option C, then it should work. But then you'd be better off setting some default values beforehand, like `foo = None` and `bar = None`. You'd still get an error if they are still None at the `C` step, but that would be clearer.

Or maybe you what you are looking for are [session states](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state)?

Comment: Thank you, what I was looking for is session states

Answer (score 0):

Session states works. Don't know if it is 100% correct, but this works for a small test example:

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu



"st.session_state object", st.session_statewith st.sidebar:
    selected = option_menu(

        menu_title= "Exposure time calculator",
        options=['A', 'B', 'C'],

    )
    
if selected == 'A':
    param1 = st.number_input('val1', value=20.0, key='key1')
    param2 = st.number_input('val2', value = 30.0, key = 'key2')
  
elif selected == 'B':
    add = st.session_state.key1 + st.session_state.key2
    divide = st.session_state.key1/st.session_state.key2
    st.write(add)
    st.write(divide)
```